# Message added in Info.plist for camera and photo library appears multiple times in alert asking for permissions

Tags: swift, xcode

I am building an app in which user can select multiple images using DKImagePickerController library. The issue is in the alert controller asking for permissions. 1)The message added in Info.plist for Camera "App would like to access Camera" appears multiple times. 2)Also in the alert for gallery permission the message added in Info.plist for Camera and gallery both appears together.

I have tried two approaches 1)Request access for Camera and Gallery manually and then using library's image picker and 2)Through the library which handles it itself. The same issue happens in both cases. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
//Code for camera access
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in
                if response {
                    //access granted
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      //perform Operation
                        self.showImgPicker()
                    }
                } else {
                    self.showAlertForPermissions()
                }
            }

//Code for Photos
            let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
            if photos == .notDetermined {
                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
                    if status == .authorized{
                        self.showImgPicker()
                    } else {
                        self.showAlertForPermissions()
                    }
                })
            }
```

Please let me know if I am missing something in my question

Comment: Nobody can even tell under which class you are writing those lines of code.

Comment: You need to write permission code in camera selection / Library selection.

Comment: @ElTomato I have added these lines of code on click of button for uploading image